# $z^2=x^2+y^2$ Prove that $4\mid xyz$ ($xyz$ is divided by $4$)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$z^2=x^2+y^2$ where $x,\ y,\ z$ - integers
Prove that $4\mid xyz$ ($xyz$ is divided by $4$)

All possible rest in divided by $4$ in this case is $1$. That's all I noticed.

Comment: Can we assume that they are all integers? Can we assume they are all positive?

Comment: yes, sure, that's right

Comment: The second line of this question doesn't make sense. I cannot understand what you are saying.

Comment: In General, prove that: $2mn(m^2+n^2)(m^2-n^2)=60K$

Comment: The question is only in the first line. The second was a part of my solution:) Or maybe what I noticed. I could erase it if it is false

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/pythTripleDiv.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple),

$x=2ab,y=a^2-b^2$

If $2|ab,4|x$

Else $(ab,2)=1\implies a^2,b^2\equiv1\pmod8\implies8|(a^2-b^2)$

Answer (score 1):

If an integer $n$ is not divisible by $4$, then it is equal to $1,2,3,5,6,$ or $7$ mod $8$. So $n^2$ is equal to $1$ or $4$ mod $8$.

Hence if neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $4$, then $z^2 = x^2+y^2$ is equal to $0, 2,$ or $5$ mod $8$; in particular, $z^2$ is not equal to $1$ or $4$ mod $8$. And so $z$ must be divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 0):

From the wikipedia page for pythagorean triples (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Elementary_properties_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) , it lists that always, one of A or B is divisible by 4, and when multiplied together, this makes the entire thing divisible by 4.

Why is this true? Well, one of A or B must be even (two odds added together could never make an even square, due to their mod 4 remainder), and all even squares are divisible by 4, so one of A or B is divisible by 4